# How to plot multiple RGB coordinates in chromaticity diagram

Tags: python, numpy, colors, cielab

I am facing some problems with plotting RGB values into a chromaticity diagram:

I have some different RGB values and I want to plot them into a chromaticity diagram to make them visual. I want to make them visual because of I have to presentate them and I want that everyone can see the colordifference.

With the colour package in Python I can make the chromaticity diagram and I can plot 1 RGB value. When I add some more RGB value I get an error.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from colour.plotting import *

RGB = np.array([79, 2, 45], [87, 12, 67])

plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(
    RGB,)
```

And I receive this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\Overige\Cie.py", line 8, in 
RGB = np.array([79, 2, 45], [87, 12, 67])
TypeError: Field elements must be 2- or 3-tuples, got '87

In this diagram I want to plot my RGB values:
[image]

In total I would like to plot arround 20 RGB values into this diagram.

Can someone help me to fix this or is there a better/easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to see, but from the error, I thin you are thinking "numpy" way, and the library on classical way. So I think you should iterate every point, and plot each single point in the figure. And as last point: chromaticity diagrams should never be plotted in colour: it gives wrong idea on colours, which are later very difficult to correct (e.g. the central point is white, black, gray, but it can be seen also as redish, greenish, bluish, etc., and you are representing out of gamut colours (and the terminal colour should go to orangish, and there is no fix low limit)

Comment: So it should be something like this? 
RGB1 = np.array([79, 2, 45])
RGB2 = np.array([87, 12, 67])


plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(
    RGB1, RGB2)

I can follow you depending on the plotted colours, do you know a way to plot them all in black for example?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about the error.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 2 additional questions: How can I make the plots black instead of white and is it possible to add a label per plot? @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: I do not know. For the second part, I think it is just a matplotlib diagram and so you can assign and change things (or you add parameters in the function, according generic parameters of mathplotlib). For the first part: I think it may be possible, but i do not known the `color` package so well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @giacomo-catenazzi answer is correct, there is some more subtlety going on here.

The expectation for the `colour.plotting.plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931` definition input is to be linear floating point RGB data, encoded using sRGB colourspace as a default.

Here, your RGB values are integer and could be 8-bit non-linearly encoded sRGB values, thus you might need to convert them to floating-point representation and decode them:

```py
import colour
import numpy as np
from colour.plotting import *

RGB = colour.models.eotf_inverse_sRGB(np.array([[79, 2, 45], [87, 12, 67]]) / 255)

plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(RGB)
```

[image: CIE Chromaticity Diagram]

Basically, you need to know how they have been encoded so that internally, the definition does the correct maths to present them.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `np.array` wrongly:
instead of `np.array([79, 2, 45], [87, 12, 67])`, you should use `np.array([[79, 2, 45], [87, 12, 67]])`. Note that the first argument should contain the data, so you should define an array of an array, and not giving `np.array` a series of vectors.

The function `plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931` can use the numpy array (I was wrong in comments), as you see in the example in [plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/develop/generated/colour.plotting.plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931.html) documentation.